# Check if character is in string

Tags: common-lisp

In Common Lisp, is there a predicate to test whether a given character is part of a string? Or more generally, if an element is a member of a vector?

Something like:

```
(char-in #\o "foo")
```

I was able to implement it as

```
(defun char-in (c s)
  (member c (coerce s 'list)))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I also propose this doc: https://lispcookbook.github.io/cl-cookbook/data-structures.html#sequences

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Strings are vectors. Vectors are sequences.**

Strings are vectors and [sequences](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm). So all operations for them apply:

**Find an item:**

```
CL-USER 59 > (find #\X "fooXbar")
#\X

CL-USER 60 > (find #\x "fooXbar")
NIL
```

**Find the position of an item:**

```
CL-USER 61 > (position #\x "fooXbar")
NIL

CL-USER 62 > (position #\X "fooXbar")
3
```

**Search for a subsequence:**

```
CL-USER 63 > (search "X" "fooXbar")
3

CL-USER 64 > (search "x" "fooXbar")
NIL
```

**Default test is EQL**

All functions use `EQL` as the default test, but you can use another one - for example a case-insensitive find would be:

```
CL-USER 65 > (find #\x "fooXbar" :test #'char-equal)
#\X
```

Comment: I think the code that is most similar to what I had in mind is: (some (lambda (x) (char= x #\o) "foo").